# How to run action in Ember Controller afterRender

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am new to ember framework. I just want to execute a function that is defined inside the actions hook after the rendering completes.

```
var Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
        console.log("foo");
    }
  }
});
Ember.run.schedule("afterRender",this,function() {
  this.send("foo");
}
```

But the above code is not working.
I just want to know, is it possible to run `foo()` afterRender?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use `init`:

```
App.Controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function () {
    this._super();
    Ember.run.schedule("afterRender",this,function() {
      this.send("foo");
    });
  },

  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      console.log("foo");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: the solution may cause test error "Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run". How to walk around this?

Comment: When in testing mode Ember does not auto start a run loop.  You can create a run look explicitly by wrapping the schedule call in an Ember.run() and it will work in tests.